How does nautilus mount CD drives?
I tried running a different DE and failed mounting a CD drive multiple times no matter what I did. Yet running nautilus and mounting my CD drive through there worked instantly.
What does nautilus do or how do I track the applications/commands it uses?

You've not provided any Ubuntu product & importantly release details; but nautilus doesn't pass to shell & run a command, it calls the OS using an API.  It is the equivalent though of a mount command.

In the background it is udisks2 who mounts it. You can check it by running in terminal udisksctl monitor  In different DE's you have to ajust the automount option if you wish this in different places.

@guiverc I understand that that calls the OS, but what exactly is the equivalent mount parameters that nautilus uses?

@nobody The udisks monitor outputs nothing when nautilus mounts the CD drive. And mounting through udisks gives me the error: Mount failed: Error mounting: mount: /media/disk: can't read superblock on /dev/sr0

Did you write something in /etc/fstab if so erase it please. Normally udisks2 mount it in folder /media//username
